# How to achieve dynamic text under icon in the best way

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement 2 `Icons` in a `Row` and under each `Icon` some text

My current implementation:

```
   ButtonBar(
                        alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.directions_car,
                              size: 55.0,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.streetview,
                              size: 55.0,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 10.0, 0, 0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('some text',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0
                            ),
                            ), 
                            Text('some text'),
                            ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

My problem is that my text should be dynamic, So every time the text changed, the location of my text changes and sometimes it look really ugly.

How can in place the text in a better way that is posted here?

Comment: Do you want the text always to be below an icon?

Comment: yes, the text should always be below the icon

Comment: So you have ButtonBar,Padding widgets inside a Column?

Comment: Exactly @PraneethDhanushkaFernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.. so what I have done is I added both Icon and Text inside a Column so they will behave as a group

```
    ButtonBar(
            alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.directions_car,
                      size: 55.0,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text('some text'),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.streetview,
                      size: 55.0,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text('some text'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: I just added to your code some padding to the left, and now it's look nice